# Set an argument and call a function with onClick()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form with some fields, which can be filled with speech recognition. I click on a button to play audio, then speech recognition starts listening.

The problem is for some reasons `setBtnName('name')` doesn't set the value and I get an error that `__.mp3` `doesn't exist`.

I believe my approach to call a function `playName()` that `sets` an argument and call another `function` inside is incorrect. Maybe someone knows another way to set an argument and call a function with `onClick()` directly?

[image]

```
const [btnName, setBtnName] = useState('')

function playName(){
   setBtnName('name')
   playSound()
}

function playAge(){
   setBtnName('age')
   playSound()
    }

const audio = [`${btnName}.mp3`]

function playSound(){
//Play sound and start recognition 
}

useState(){
//use {btnName} as a value for json file to compare it with transcript
}
    return (
    <div>
      <p>Microphone: {listening ? 'on' : 'off'}</p>
      <button
        onClick={playName}
        type="button"> Name
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={playAge}
        type="button"> Age
      </button>
      <div>{name}</div>
      <div>{age}</div>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use your buttonName or `audio` inside `playSound`? In this case, it's not there yet. setBtnName will take effect in the next render.

You'd need either `playSound('age')` / `playSound('name')` or `useRef` or `setTimeout` or combine `useState` and `useEffect`. So there are several ways.

Just one of the ways that seems more like what you want to achieve:

```
function playName(){
   setBtnName('name')
   playSound('name')
}

function playAge(){
   setBtnName('age')
   playSound('age')
    }



function playSound(name){
const audio = [`${name}.mp3`]
//Play sound and start recognition 
}
```